# Choosing transistor for this circuit

Tags: transistors

I have a problem: 
I have a circuit with a MSP430 MCU.
I have a sensor which is supposed to be powered in 3.3V. My main power rail in my circuit is 3.3V. I need to power on and power off this sensor using a GPIO to pilot the power, so I suppose I need to use a transistor BJT being controlled by GPIO to let go the current in on/off mode into the sensor. 
Problem is power rail value = sensor value and my transistor got VCEsat = 0.7V (or I can also change it to -0.7V) 
So how do I manage with the Resistor value (R208) ?

[image]

Comment: What sensor are you trying to turn on / off? If the sensor draws less than 3-4mA, you can power it straight off a pin on the MSP430.  The datasheet specs a max current source of 6mA from a pin on the MSP430

Comment: @chendrix the sensor draw 100mA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a collector current of 100 mA, the BC807 would have a typical saturation voltage of about 50 mV:
[image: BC807 VCE(sat)]

However, even if you can live with this 50 mV, this would require a base current of about 10 mA, which is too much for your MSP430FR2311.

---

A P-channel MOSFET can give you a smaller voltage drop:
[image: switching power to sensor with P-channel MOSFET]

This requires that Q1 is a FET with an R<sub>DS(on)</sub> value of much less than 500 mΩ; some widely-used models would be DMP2066, IRLML6401, or FDN338P.

Comment: Thank you very much;, I am going to implement this. Thank you for the scheme ,it helps a lot.

Comment: I will go with th fairchild one.

Comment: I have another question: I have similar concern with using a 3.3V relay instead. Should I use a Mosfet or a BJT ?

Comment: Again, depends on how much of a voltage drop over the transistor you can afford.

Answer (score 2):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgBlMN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The sensor will always be connected to ground on one end. The power supply can be enabled or disabled by the MCU. this is just the basic FET based switch. Advantage here is that, the sensor can always have ground reference. FETs can be from [TI](http://www.ti.com.cn/cn/lit/ds/symlink/tps22924c.pdf). the threshold voltage is well with in 2 V to turn on the FET.

Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: What is the purpose of the N-channel FET?

Comment: To turn on P Mosfet, gate has to be certain voltage below the source. Since source is at 3.3 V, N Mosfet helps in connecting gate of P Mosfet to ground. In order to turn off P Mosfet, N Mosfet is turned off by MCU. Assume, if the sensor supply would have been 5 V. Then, if we didn't had N Mosfet, the P Mosfet cannot be turned off by the MCU gpio. Because , maximum output voltage of gpio is 3.3. The voltage at the source pin of P fet is 5 V. It will not be turned off. Just a precaution.

Comment: In other words, you are using the N-ch FET as a level shifter. This is not necessary in this particular circuit.

Comment: Not necessary. Yes.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of R208 and use a low on-resistance N channel MOSFET instead of the BC817. Make sure the MOSFET is turned on enough with a 3V3 IO line - look at Alpha and Omega - they have some low gate threshold devices.

Answer (score 1):

I second Andy's answer. Here is how the LEDs on my CC3200 Launchpad are connected. You could use a similar arrangement and replace the LEDs with your sensor. VCC_BRD is 3.3V and the GPIO lines are active high at 3.3V.

[image]

Comment: yes but your LED are not powered in 3.3V since you have the resistor there. in my case my sensor has to be powered by 3.3V

Comment: @Chris: The resistors are current limiting resistors for the LEDs. You can remove them along with the LEDs (as long as your sensor does not need a current limiting resistor).

Comment: what i don't understand is why use a mosfet instead of a bjt ?

Comment: MOSFETs do not require much current on their gate pins to turn them ON. Since their Ron is quite low there is less drop across them which makes them more advantageous in low power applications.